# Search for posts by user in private Facebook Group

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups, facebook-search

I would like to view all the posts (and maybe comments) made by a single user in a private Facebook group. Searching by their name does not work because their name is mentioned so often in other people's posts.

Is there any advanced search functionality in Facebook private groups?

Comment: Doesn't look like it, no. The intragroup search is quite simplistic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Facebook Graph Search

"Posts in GroupName by FirstNameLastName"

`https://www.facebook.com/search/str/GROUP_ID/stories-in/USER_ID/stories-by/intersect`

Replace GROUP_ID for the private group ID and the USER_ID for the person you are checking.

> (and maybe comments)

"Posts in GroupName commented on by FirstNameLastName"

`https://www.facebook.com/search/str/GROUP_ID/stories-in/USER_ID/stories-commented/intersect`

Comment: Cool, the search bar at the top works much better! Is there anyway to filter out events, too?

Comment: `Posts in GroupName by FirstNameLastName` suddenly stopped working, but the URL still works like a charm

Comment: @Leftium yes, currently searching using phrases has been unpredictable for some strange reason. All the calls should still work from the url.